# Why won't the array fit my curve?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Hey im kind of new to blender and modeling and im trying to fit this barbed wire to my curve but the only result i get is either a wierd shape or a of set line of barbed wires... and it wont even fit my curve.. anyone has had the same problem as me that knows how to fix it?

kind regards Anton

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to change order in modifier stack. First Array modifier than Curve.

Comment: @LukeD i have tried that to but it doesent work :P

Comment: Ok, upload file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add it to your question as an edit.

Comment: @LukeD like this? and thank you for looking in to it <3

Answer (score 5):

[image: final]

Couple of things to make it work.

1. **Origins** of the objects should be in the the **Center of the Mass** and in the same place in space for both of them.

   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> **> Origin to Center of Mass (Volume)**
   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **> Cursor to Center**
   - <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> **> Selection to Cursor**

   > **Repeat for both objects.**

   This way we will have both objects in the center of the scene with **Origin 
   Points** in the sam place, like so:

   [image: origin]
2. Add **Array** then **Curve** modifier and set it like this:

   [image: modifiers]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the scale is applied on both the curve and object, and curve as well as the object are sharing the same origin.

Select the curve, go into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the properties panel and if the curve radius is not at 1.0, your object is deforming, set it to 1.0 and everything will look gorgeous.